# Weird scroll behaviour onRendered

Tags: jquery, meteor, iron-router

When the page first renders, it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the element.

However, whenever I click another chat room from the left side, it behaves correctly if the room has less messages than the previous chat room. If the clicked room has more messages, it only scrolls equal to previous room's height.

My onRendered:

```
Template.singleRequest.onRendered(function () {
    $('#all-messages').scrollTop($('#all-messages').prop("scrollHeight"));
});
```

I believe the reason is I have a second yield. When you click a chatroom/request from the left side, it renders to the right side with iron:router

```
{{> yield "right-panel"}}
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried

```
Template.singleRequest.onRendered(function () {
    Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
        $('#all-messages').scrollTop($('#all-messages').prop("scrollHeight"));
    });
});
```

**EDIT**:

I also tried giving an id to the last element and scrolling to that one but still behaves the same. Very weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a simple trick.

So, inside my singleRequest, I created a new template for each messages inside.

```
{{#each messages}}
    {{> singleMessage}}
{{/each}}
```

That way, whenever I click another room from the left, it renders singleMessage template once again and the scroll works perfectly fine.

```
Template.singleMessage.onRendered(function () {
    $('#all-messages').scrollTop($('#all-messages').prop("scrollHeight"));
});
```